# CQ5 Global search component not displaying excerpt for search results

Tags: aem

We have used the globalSearch component for site search but result returned are not displaying **excerpt** .

If we point the search path geometrix website pages it does display the **excerpt** but if we point it to our website("/content/mysite") we get valid search results but no **excerpt**.

Let me know whats the roots cause of this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation on the **[Search](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/foundation/Search.html)** class, since 5.3+

> Excerpt properties can now only be specified in the configuration of the QueryBuilder interface [i.e.at `http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.search.impl.builder.QueryBuilderImpl`].

Have you tried looking at this configuration to see what properties it's using to build excerpts on the Geometrixx pages & cross-checking that you have values in these same properties on your site?

Comment: Thanks If we add a specific property name to the QueryBuilderImpl it shows in Excerpt but our website  has different custom components for example we have a component which reads excel from DAM to display content ..now if we want to display the excerpts as the content from xls which get displayed on screen.How can we achieve it

Comment: I presume that you'd need to write some custom search for this — the content from the Excel document doesn't live on the page that you want to return in the search results, so the data from the document isn't available to appear in the excerpt OOTB.